# How to get a row by a index?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I'm trying to build a function that has a for loop and, when find some condition, change the color of a row. But when I try the code bellow, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getRowIndex in object Sheet.

So, in this case, given that I have the row position through the `i` variable, how can I, using the `i` value, select the corresponding row in the sheet in a way I can change the background of the entire row?

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sourceSpreadsheetID = ss.getId();
    var oldSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
    var oldWorksheet = oldSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("students");
    var newData = newWorksheet.getDataRange().getValues();

 // Iterates through the new sheet rows
    for(i=1; i<newData.length; i++){
    var currentRow = oldWorksheet.getRowIndex(i);
    currentRow.setBackgroundRGB(255, 222, 173).setNote("any note"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the getRange() function of the "Sheet" type to accomplish this.

```
var currentRow = oldWorksheet.getRange(i /* specify the row here*/, column /* Specify the number of columns here */)
currentRow.setBackgroundRGB(255, 222, 173).setNote("any note");
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured this one out by using the Google Sheet feature **"Get link to this range"**, this link contains a query param `range=[Your Range Here]` in this case it will be `range=index:index`

So the solution would be:

```
const getRowByIndex = (index) => currentSheet.getRange(`${index}:${index}`)
```